# Returning multiple JSON objects from PHP to jQuery via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This question has been asked already but it is not solving my specific query. What I am trying to achieve is whenever a user inputs the pincode, via AJAX I am sending the pincode to PHP and returning the results with that pincode. If a single area is mapped to a particular pincode then my code works. But if there are multiple areas with same pincode then my code breaks. I have tried multiple ways. I have even tried this: [Link](https://diffiebosman.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/how-to-return-multiple-json-objects-from-php-to-jquery-with-ajax/)

Here is my code

```
$('.input-pc').on('keyup change', function(){
    PincodeId = $(this).attr('id');
    PincodeVal = $("#" + PincodeId).val();
    checkPincodeLength = PincodeVal.length;
    if(checkPincodeLength == 6){
        $('#' + PincodeId).next().next('.invalid-feedback').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../auth/regrequest.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: 'current_pincode='+PincodeVal,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log('pc: '+data);
                $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                   console.log(val);
               })
                                   
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#' + PincodeId).next().next('.invalid-feedback').html('<span><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Pincode must be of 6 digits</span>');
    }
});
```

I have even tried removing the dataType and parsed the data using JSON.parse. This too did not work.

My PHP code looks like this

```
if(isset($_POST['current_pincode']) && !empty($_POST['current_pincode'])){
    $current_pincode = $_POST['current_pincode'];
        $query26 = $dbc->prepare("SELECT a.area_id, a.city_id, a.state_id, b.state_name, c.city_name, d.area_name FROM pincodes a, states b, cities c, areas d WHERE a.pincode_code = ? AND a.state_id = b.state_id AND a.city_id = c.city_id AND a.area_id = d.area_id GROUP BY area_id ORDER BY area_id");
        $query26->bindParam(1, $current_pincode);
        $query26->execute();
        $citystate = '';
        $city_id = '';
        //$citystatearray = array(
           // 'CityState' => array(),
        //);
        //$i = 0;
        //while ($getcitystate = $query26->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
         //   $citystatearray['CityState'][$i++] = $getcitystate;
         //   echo json_encode($citystatearray); 
       // }
        foreach($query26 AS $getcitystate){
            
            // $state_id = $getcitystate['state_id'];
            // $state_name = $getcitystate['state_name'];
            // $city_id = $getcitystate['city_id'];
            // $city_name = $getcitystate['city_name'];
            // $area_name = $getcitystate['area_name'];
            // $rowCount = $query26->rowCount();
            
            // //$citystate .= $area_name.',';
            // //$pct = $getcitystate['pincodetime'];if(count($area_name) == 1){echo 'only one';}else{echo 'more than 1';}
             if($rowCount == 1){
            //     $citystate = 
            //                 array(
            //                     'current_pincode' => $current_pincode,
            //                     'state_id' => $state_id,
            //                     'state_name' => $state_name,
            //                     'city_id' => $city_id,
            //                     'city_name' => $city_name,
            //                     'area_name' => $area_name,
            //                     'rowcount' => $rowCount
            //                  );
             }else{
                
                $citystate .= 
                            array(
                                
                                                'current_pincode' => $current_pincode,
                                                'state_id' => $state_id,
                                                'state_name' => $state_name,
                                                'city_id' => $city_id,
                                                'city_name' => $city_name,
                                                'area_name' => array('area_name_inner' => $area_name),
                                                'area_name' => $area_name,
                                                'rowcount' => $rowCount
                                                
                        );
             }
            //echo $citystate;
            
           
        }echo json_encode(
            array(
                'citystate' => $citystate
            )); //echo json_encode(
        //     array(
        //         'citystate' => $citystate
        //     ));//echo $citystate;
        //echo $city_id;
       // echo $citystate1 = $city_id.','.$rowCount.','.$citystate;
}
```

I have not removed the comments to show the different ways i tried to output the data but in vain. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Put all the results in an array, and then encode the entire array as JSON.

Comment: Why are you looping through the record set? Cannot you just fetchALl() and JSON_ENCODE only that and pass back? I think this sounds similar to @Barmar

Comment: I have done that @Barmar . If you can see, I have put all the results in an array and encoded it

Comment: `$citystate = '';` creates a string, not an array. `$citystate .= array(...)` concatenates the string `Array` to that string.

Comment: You should initialize `$citystate = [];` and then do `$citystate[] = array(...)` to add a row to the array.

Comment: @Barmar I will try this way and update

Comment: @BrokenArrow I tried using fetchAll() and I am able to get the JSON objects in my console.log. I get multiple objects as desired. Now iam parsing the data JSON.parse and using $.each to loop through the objects. Please let me know if I am correct in my approach

Comment: Absolutely correct

Comment: @BrokenArrow I am able to retrieve data in the way that I need. But now I need to remove duplicate entries. Here's my JSON response `[{"area_id":"840","1":"22","state_id":"17","2":"17","city_name":"Bengaluru","4":"Bengaluru","area_name":"Bangalore Bazaar ","5":"Bangalore Bazaar "},{"area_id":"844","0":"844","state_id":"17","2":"17","city_name":"Bengaluru","4":"Bengaluru","area_name":"Bangalore G.P.O. ","5":"Bangalore G.P.O. "}]` I need to output all the areas with unique city names. Every area_name is mapped to one city_name in the DB.

Comment: `var uniq = {};
                $.each($jsonobj, function(index, val) {
                        var un = uniq[val['city_name']] = uniq[val['city_name']] || {};
                        un[val['city_name']] = true;
                })`   I have tried this code by seeing some other response but I quite did not understand how it works and this code does the work and outputs me this `{
    "Bengaluru": {
        "Bengaluru": true
    }
}` Now I dont know how to access these :(

Comment: You should remove duplicate on the server side PHP, that will be far more easier.

Comment: Can you please give me a suggestion on how to do it.